# UNKNOWN: unknown error, open

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm

При сборке проекта `gulp` выдает ошибку такого вида:

> UNKNOWN: unknown error, open

При том, что ранее я уже работал с этим проектом через `gulp` и все было хорошо, а теперь эта ошибка стала выскакивать постоянно, но бывают моменты, когда она не выскакивает, не могу понять, в чем проблема? С другим проектом все нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

gulpfile.js:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  less = require('gulp-less'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
  imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
  pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
  htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
  cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat')



var path = {

  build: {
    html: 'dest',
    less: 'app/css',
    js: 'dest/js',
    img: 'dest/img',
    fonts: 'dest/fonts',
    libs: 'dest/libs',
    css: 'dest/css'
  },

  src: {
    html: 'app/*.html',
    less: 'app/less/styles.less',
    js: 'app/js/*.js',
    img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*',
    libs: 'app/libs/**/*.*',
    css: 'app/css/*.css'
  },

  watch: {
    html: 'app/*.html',
    js: 'app/js/*.js',
    less: 'app/less/**/*.less',
    img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
    fonts: 'fonts/**/*.*',
    css: 'app/css/*.css'
  }
}

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "dest",
      index: "organizations.html"
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('build:html', function() {
  gulp.src([path.src.html, '!app/header.html'])
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(htmlmin({
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})


gulp.task('build:less', function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.less)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.less))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('build:css', ['build:less'], function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
      loadMaps: true
    }))
    .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})

gulp.task('build:js', function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.js)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})

gulp.task('build:img', function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.img)
    .pipe(imagemin([
      imagemin.svgo({
        plugins: [{
            optimizationLevel: 3
          },
          {
            progessive: true
          },
          {
            interlaced: true
          },
          {
            removeViewBox: false
          },
          {
            removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false
          },
          {
            cleanupIDs: false
          }
        ]
      }),
      imagemin.gifsicle(),
      imagemin.jpegtran(),
      imagemin.optipng()
    ]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})

gulp.task('build:fonts', function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})

gulp.task('build:libs', function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.libs)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.libs))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(path.watch.html, ['build:html'])
  gulp.watch(path.watch.css, ['build:css'])
  gulp.watch(path.watch.fonts, ['build:fonts'])
  gulp.watch(path.watch.libs, ['build:libs'])
  gulp.watch(path.watch.js, ['build:js'])
  gulp.watch(path.watch.img, ['build:img'])
  gulp.watch(path.watch.less, ['build:css'])
})

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync', 'watch', 'build:html', 'build:img', 'build:css', 'build:js', 'build:libs', 'build:fonts']);
```

В чем может быть проблема?